# Pandas find consecutive rows where following row meets condition

Tags: python, pandas

So I hace a Data frame that looks like this:

| index | Time | status | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-27 08:51:49 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-11-27 09:32:49 | B | 1 |
| 3 | 2020-11-27 09:32:50 | C | 1 |
| 4 | 2020-11-27 12:05:08 | B | 2 |
| 5 | 2020-11-27 12:10:08 | C | 2 |
| 6 | 2020-11-27 12:10:58 | A | 2 |
| 7 | 2020-11-27 12:12:12 | A | 3 |
| 8 | 2020-11-27 12:31:15 | B | 3 |
| 9 | 2020-11-27 12:31:17 | C | 3 |

I want to filter only the rows where column `status = A` is followed by a row where `status = B`
Result:

| index | Time | status | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-27 08:51:49 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-11-27 09:32:49 | B | 1 |
| 7 | 2020-11-27 12:12:12 | A | 3 |
| 8 | 2020-11-27 12:31:15 | B | 3 |

Thanks

Comment: What are the rows where `phase = 2` not in the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `groupby` with `shift`

```
cond1 = df.groupby('phase')['status'].shift(-1).eq('B')  & df['status'].eq('A')
cond2 = df.groupby('phase')['status'].shift().eq('A')  & df['status'].eq('B')
df[cond1|cond2]
   index                Time status  phase
0      1  2020-11-2708:51:49      A      1
1      2  2020-11-2709:32:49      B      1
6      7  2020-11-2712:12:12      A      3
7      8  2020-11-2712:31:15      B      3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["next_status"] = df.status.shift(-1) 
df["prior_status"] = df.status.shift(1)
a = df.next_status.eq("B") & df.status.eq("A")
b = df.prior_status.eq("A") & df.status.eq("B")
df[a | b]
```

the new column "next_status" is the status column, shifted up by one.
so if the current status = A and the following status = B, they will be next to each other, same logic applies to prior status. Then you can use the conditions to subset the df.

Comment: My apologies, you are right, like this it should get both rows.